# Extracting distances along a line from postcode a centroid to the nearest point (bus stop)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, point, distance, line

I'm looking to measure the distance from postcode centroids (point file) in a city to the nearest bus stop (point file) along the road network (line file).

In QGIS I can calculate the distance but it is not measured along the road network. I'm sure this can be performed in GRASS GIS however, but unsure to how (v.distance maybe). Its the `from` and `to` part of the v.distance code I'm struggling with, as I can't find where to specify along the network, or does all three files need to be connected to each other and in different layers?.

Comment: I think the GRASS tool [v.net.path](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.net.path.html) might suit your needs but I never used it so can't comment on it much :)